# Cannot convert type Nancy.ErrorHandling.DefaultStatusCodeHandler.DefaultStatusCodeHandlerResult to Nancy.Response

Tags: exception, owin, nancy

has anyone seen such exception before?

> Cannot convert type 
>   Nancy.ErrorHandling.DefaultStatusCodeHandler.DefaultStatusCodeHandlerResult
>   to Nancy.Response

I'm using nancy.owin with old asp.net mvc site.

this error happens when I'm configuring OWIN middleware using app.Map(path...) method

if I apply nancy middleware directly to the app (IAppBuilder) everything works as expected

but when I use app.Map(path) I get such exception. BUT: as a result in my postman I get 404 The resource you have requested cannot be found.

Comment: We cannot help you if you post only the error. You need to post *the code causing* the error. Otherwise it's like trying to fix a car by staring at the smoke coming out of the back.